# How to access old entity value in ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a small ASP.Net mvc3 application and I am on the edit part. I have the default template:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id); 
    return View(user);
}

public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    //(Here access to old user name for example)
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If i do user.name I have the new value but I want to access the db value before the save.

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it work with a small trick:

```
db.Users.Attach(user);
var current = db.Entry(user).CurrentValues.Clone();
db.Entry(user).Reload();
//Do you user(from db) stuff
db.Entry(user).CurrentValues.SetValues(current);
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: +1 nicely done. Was just adding a comment with a similar suggestion to my previous post when I noticed you have already solved it.

Comment: db.Entry(user).GetDatabaseValues() will be a better candidate than CurrentValues, in case the attributes were modified in code after they were pulled from DB.

Answer (score 2):

context.Entry(YourEntity).GetDatabaseValues().ToObject() as YourEntity

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    User oldUser = db.Users.Find(user.id);
    // oldUser object represents the user before the modification
    ...
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried that but it gives me the Exception : An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the lkaradashkov's answer. You can try using the option AsNoTracking() to prevent Entity Framework from tracking it.

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    User oldUser = db.Users.AsNoTracking().Single(x=>x.id.equals(user.id));
    // oldUser object represents the user before the modification
    ...
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get old value and new value separate :

```
 //user.UserName = "oldtest"     
 user.UserName = "Test"     
 var originalValues = db.Entry(user).OriginalValues.Clone();
 var originalval = originalValues.GetValue<string>("UserName");
 var currentvalue = db.Entry(user).CurrentValues.Clone();
 var curretval = currentvalue.GetValue<string>("UserName");
```

This will return originalval  as old value before set new UserName as "oldtest" and curretval return new UserName as "Test"